# Change Background of ListView on Pressed dont works, still Blue how default

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-styles

Im try change the background of the List Item on my Listview Android but nothing i try works, i want make transparent, i make that:

item

list_item_favorite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_favorites_background"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_name"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_favorites_textview_background"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and make the drawable correspondent

listview_favorites_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparente" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparente" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

and make the color transparent

```
<color name="transparente">#00000000</color>
```

But when click the background of list item turns blue how is default, i dont know what is wrong, i try put the style also in ListView but dont works, please someone now what is wrong ? If possible by the style, dont whit code..but if not exists by the style can be by code, thanks much, this is big problem, lack only that to me publish my app, thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this property to your ListView (not the TextView, the ListView):

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

overallduka you have created a transparent single row for your list but list itself must be set to transparent.
I believe this will help. It works for me

```
 <ListView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>
```